# Raycast not hitting objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's like a mario game. The player is jumping around and has to collect some items.

The problem is that my ray isn't colliding with the item box colliders.

I need the ray to know, so i can destroy the right item that the player has collided.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
{
    if((colisor.gameObject.name == "floor" || colisor.gameObject.name == "floor2" || colisor.gameObject.name == "floor3"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("jump", false);
        anim.SetFloat("speed", 0);
    }

    if (colisor.gameObject.name == "space(Clone)")
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(player.position, transform.right);
        Debug.Log("hit1");

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            BoxCollider bc2d = hit.collider as BoxCollider;
            Debug.Log("hit2");

            if (bc2d != null)
            {
                Destroy(bc2d.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm almost certain there's a duplicate for this, but `Physics` is not `Physics2D`

Comment: also make sure your start point isnt inside another collider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing 3d and 2d physics; `Physics` will only look for 3d objects, so you should be using [`Physics2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html) instead. This raycast may still fail if the cast starts inside the target, because the surface normals point in the wrong direction.

Also note that since you already have the [`Collision2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html), you can just grab the `otherCollider` and shouldn't need to raycast in the first place.

Comment: I was wondering if i could have just done that... Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

`Physics.Raycast` isn't working with 2D objects. Instead you need to use `Physics2D.Raycast` or `Graphic Raycaster`.

Raycast2D - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html

Graphic Raycaster - https://docs.unity3d.com/eng/current/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html